# How do I convert this oracle date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to convert from one date format to another. I am not sure how to write the functions.

My source date looks like `01/15/2009 01:23:15`

The format I need is `01152009`.

Thanks

Comment: a date format is only one in oracle, maybe you want to show it as a string. What did you try till now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/15/2009 01:23:15','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'MMDDYYY')
```

More info here,
http://psoug.org/reference/date_func.html

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?  It assumes the date is in date format but will work with timestamp

select to_char(YourDateField,'DDMMYYYY') from dual;

You can always convert it back to a date using the TO_DATE function if you need that format.

Answer (score 0):

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/15/2009 01:23:15','MM/DD/YYYY MI:HH:SS'),'MMDDYYYY') from dual
```

if your field is already of data type date then you should only do:

```
select TO_CHAR(<fieldname>,'ddmmyyyy') ...
```